# Most active Mac code editor 2014

Tags: editor, osx-mavericks

As of 2014, which Mac code editor has the most active user-base or dev cycle in terms of addons/snippets/bundles/plugins - keeping it up to date with new standards and practices? For example: HTML5, CSS3, Coffeescript, Markdown, preprocessing.

For background info I have been using Textmate 1 happily until recently when I installed Mavericks, which breaks the GetBundles bundle due to Ruby <1.9 dependencies. This was a wakeup call that TM1 is very old and feels semi-abandoned. I tried TM2 but it does not replicate all of TM1 features yet - GetBundles for example.

Comment: The answer to all questions like *Which editor should I use ?* is always either Emacs or Vi and one of those answers is wrong.

Comment: Both of those answers are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using Textmate then you would love [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/), from what I hear it is very close to TextMate and it's an awesome text editor by itself.

Personally I use macvim and Sublime Text first more for code writing the second more as a general purpose editor.

Comment: Thx a lot for sharing and I'll accept your answer because I agree Sublime is the new Textmate, at least until TM2 comes out of beta!